# How to find the reduced coordinates of reciprocal lattice vector which defines the kslice plane in first brillouin zone?

Tags: quantum-espresso, k-points, brillouin-zone, wannier90, fermi-surface

I am trying to get the Fermi contour lines of an FCC crystal system. For this, I am trying to use the wannier90 program. I have already done the wannierzation part successfully. Now I am trying to get the Fermi surface contour lines. But for this I need three parameters, `kslice_corner`, `kslice_b1`, `kslice_b2`. `kslice_corner` is the coordinates of the corner of kplane slice of our interest. `kslice_b1` and `kslice_b2` are the reduced coordinates of the reciprocal lattice vectors defining that plane. Say if I need fermi contour lines in `kz=0` plane. What is the procedure to find the above three parameters for `kz=0` plane for FCC? How can I achieve this? Is there any visualization tool for kslice planes and its coordinates? Below is the image of first Brillouin zone of FCC lattice:

[image]

Please help with this.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you had any luck with this over the last 5.5 months? Please update us! It would be nice to get this out of our unanswered queue :)

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.